# How to remove the "api" from Function App URL

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created a http function on Azure.  The URL is this:

```
https://test.azurewebsites.net/{name}
```

It works just fine.

But now I want to change the url to remove the API part of the string so the url is as short as possible, like this:

```
https://515redirect.azurewebsites.net/{name}
```

Is that possible?  I have not been able to find a setting for this in the Portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set this in `host.json` file:

```json
{
    "http": {
        "routePrefix": ""
    }
}
```

> The route prefix that applies to all routes. Use an empty string to remove the default prefix.

See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#http)